# Webpage loading too slow, ssl takes too long

Tags: html, wordpress, deployment

My website is taking too long to load. I found that HTTP is loading first, then https which takes almost 2.5 seconds and then the other contents. How can I fix this?

LetsEncrypt SSL is automatically assigned by Hostinger. I didn't do any setup in WordPress.

[image: Page Load Data]